# Can I derive values from a union type to create new union type?

Tags: typescript

```
type Cartoon = { kind: 'cat', name: 'Tom'} | { kind: 'mouse', name: 'Jerry' }

type Animal = 'cat' | 'mouse'   // how can I derive this from Cartoon?
```

I have a union type (Cartoon) of types that all contain the key "kind". I would like to create a new type (Animal) that is union type of all the values kind contains in Cartoon.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
type Cartoon = { kind: 'cat', name: 'Tom'} | { kind: 'mouse', name: 'Jerry' }
type Animal = Cartoon['kind'] // Same as 'cat' | 'mouse'
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. Done :)